# solr - programmatically create a new collection

Tags: collections, solr, schema, managed

I installed solr 5.3 and ran solr in solr cloud mode.
I easily created a new collection in the managed schema mode at the command prompt
solr create -c new_collection
this creates a new folder and updates the schema settings for me

I then tried to dup this process programmatically using the collection API
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API

I can't CREATE a new collection.  get error about config not found
i tried to CREATE a new config using the managedschema as a base but that didn't work.

what is the proper way to programmatically create a new collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr cloud stores its config into zookeeper, so you should upload to it a config files (must contains a schema.xml and solrconfig.xml). That files are stored under path configs/collection_name. You can upload files via zookeeper client lib or via zookeeper cli, read more about it at [Using ZooKeeper to Manage Configuration Files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files)

Comment: i looked at the zookeeper config manager url:
[link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files)
there doesn't appear to be a zookeeper http API. 
i have a cmd line  zkcli script or SolrJ (Java).  i'm working with python so neither appears to be an option for me